# How to find the distance between locations on two separate queries in Excel power query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have two queries titled `Review` and `Location`, containing stored address information, including longitude and latitude. Both queries have the same columns. Lat & Long are in separate columns . The `Review` query typically contains the information for 5 to 10 different stores, while the `Location` query is around 3500. I need a way to calculate the distance between the stores so I can find the nearest location to the stores in the Review query.

I found some code to calculate the distance between, but I cannot get it to work.

```
=MINX(Review,ROUND(2 * 3959 * ASIN(SQRT(SIN((Review[Lat] - Location[Lat]) * PI()/360)^2 + COS(Location[Lat] * PI()/180) * COS(Review[Lat] * PI()/180) * SIN((Review[Lon] - Location[Lon]) * PI()/360)^2)), 1))
```

Comment: Example of your data would be useful. Might help also to read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook that demonstrates the problem (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Table1 has 4 columns named [Latitude_1, Longitude_1, Latitude_2, Longitude_2] and the coordinates are in decimal [38.892456, -74.0247852] then code below generates the distance between the locations in miles (change 3959 to 6371 for kilometers) using formula:

=ACOS(SIN(lat1)*SIN(lat2)+COS(lat1)*COS(lat2)*COS(lon2-lon1))*3959

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "DistanceMiles", each Number.Acos(Number.Sin(([Latitude_1] / 180) * Number.PI) * Number.Sin(([Latitude_2] / 180) * Number.PI) + Number.Cos(([Latitude_1] / 180) * Number.PI) * Number.Cos(([Latitude_2] / 180) * Number.PI) * Number.Cos( ([Longitude_2] / 180) * Number.PI-([Longitude_1] / 180) * Number.PI)) * 3959),
in #"Added Custom"
```